# "Failed with: success/error was not called" when trying to return httpResponse in Parse

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, promise

Pardon my JS/Parse newbieness.

I'm trying to perform a Parse HTTP request within a regular function using Promises (I tried the non-promises way as well to no avail). For the life of me I can't get httpResponse.text. The code below results in "Failed with: success/error was not called".

I'm fairly sure there is more than one issue here, and perhaps my approach is way off. Note also that console.log("FML") is printed in the logs but console.log("response is " + httpResponse.text); is not.

```
function getTweets(team) {

    // some code and the params for the http request

    Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
        method: 'GET',
        url: THE_URL,
        headers: {
                 SOME_HEADER_PARAMS
        },
        body: {
        }}).then(function(httpResponse) {
             console.log("FML");
             console.log("response is " + httpResponse.text);
             return httpResponse.text;
        }).then(function(error) {
             return error;
        });
    };
```

Also note:

- console.log("FML") is printed in the logs but console.log("response
  is " + httpResponse.text); is not. I'm getting HTTP status of 200 so
  the HTTP request appears to be fine

Comment: What is `.then(function(error) { return error; });` supposed to do?

Comment: That's sloppiness/newbieness on my part. Might it be the cause of the errors?

Comment: Nah, it actually should just not do anything.

Answer (score 1):

Parse uses a different syntax for handling errors with promises. Your promise chain should look like this:

```
Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({...})
    .then(function(httpResponse) {
        console.log("FML");
        console.log("response is " + httpResponse.text);
        return httpResponse.text;
    }, function(error) {
        return error;
    });
```

Also note that most promise libraries do not use `then` to resolve errors. They typically use `catch` for error handling.

Comment: Thanks, that only covers the error, though, which is the least of my problems at the moment.

Comment: Actually, not a single promise library passes rejections to the first `.then()` callback.

Answer (score 1):

`success/error was not called` is a common error that you'll see if your Cloud Function fails to call either `response.success()` or `response.error()`. It seems like the error in your code is located outside of the sample you've provided, as it's likely your function is reaching the end of the Promise chain without either of these getting called.

Comment: Hector you were exactly right. In general your answers here and elsewhere on Parse Forums and whatnot have been really great, thanks so much.